# Full screen Frame image loading

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to make a board game in Java using AWT. I want to run this game in Full screen exclusive mode. but the `paint()` method is not working.

**Problem** is i want to load and draw an image it on full screen frame, but the traditional `paint()` method won't allow me to do that.

Comment: maybe I'm late (`PLZ HELP ASAP`) sorry that I'm later that asap time_out

Comment: Do you have an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) we can experiment with?  ..Do you have a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example below will get you full-screen on your **default screen device** with an `java.awt.Frame`.

- [Lesson: Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html) (link to oracle).

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Frame frame = new Frame("Test");
    frame.setUndecorated(true);

    frame.add(new Component() {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/"+
                                                 "wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png"));
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    });

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    gs.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
    frame.validate();
}
```

---

You can use the above example with swing aswell (just be sure to implement the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method instead of `paint`).

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: thanks for helping user 919201, but as above person said i wanted exclusive mode